# gcd of $x^4 + 2x^3 + x + 1$ and $x^5 + 2x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$ in $F_3[x]$

Tags: polynomials

I am asked to find the gcd of $x^4 + 2x^3 + x + 1$ and $x^5 + 2x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$ in $F_3[x]$ (polynomials in $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z)$.

Using Euclid's Algorithm, I first divided $x^4 + 2x^3 + x + 1$ into $x^5 + 2x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$ to get $x + 1$ remainder $2x$. I then divided $2x$ into $x^4 + 2x^3 + x + 1$ to get $2x^3 + x^2 + 2$, remainder $1$, indicating that the gcd is 1. However, in the back of the text, the answer is that the gcd is $x^2 + 1$. Is there something here that I'm not understanding correctly? I've looked over the actual long division multiple times and I can't spot an error.

Comment: Dividing $x^5+2x^3+x^2+x+1$ by $x^4+2x^3+x+1$ yields a remainder of $6x^3+2x+3$. Check your calculations again.

Comment: In $F_3$, is this not equal to $2x$?

Comment: Ah, I overlooked that we're working over $\Bbb{F}_3$. Then indeed the $\gcd$ is $1$.

Comment: The gcd is $\,x^2+1\,$ if the first ends $\,\ldots \color{#c00}-x\color{#c00}-1\,$ vs $\,x+1.$ There are no single term sign changes that cause the first to be divisible by $\,x^2+1.\ \ $